# How to change the background color of every item in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I am developing an app which has a text message interface (something like Facebook Messenger, Whatsapp, etc). I want to be able to change the background color of all the chat bubbles (a `ListView` of `TextView`s) sent by the user when they pick a new color (in a `NavigationView`).

However, with the current code that I have, I only am able to change the color after the `EditText` used to compose the message is clicked again. Or I am able to only edit the first bubble sent, but as soon as the color is changed.

Here's what I tried :

```
ItemColor1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        Toast.makeText(activity, "Couleur mise à jour", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        currentTheme = position;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("indexColorSelected",currentTheme);
        editor.apply();
        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //the following changes only the first message sent     
        for(int i=0; i<chatAdapter.getCount(); i++){
            ChatData message = chatMessageList.get(position);
            TextView msg = activity.findViewById(R.id.text);
            msg.setText(message.body);
            msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_color1);
        }
    }
});
```

`ChatData` is a custom Class that I created which looks like this :

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ArrayList<ChatData> chatMessageList;
    private Context mContext;

    ChatAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ChatData> list) {
        mContext = activity;
        chatMessageList = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    ...
}
```

Color drawable:

```
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:radius="40dp"/>

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="#01f1fa"
        android:startColor="#0189ff"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

`getView()` method of the Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ChatData message = chatMessageList.get(position);
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msglist, parent, false);

    TextView msg = vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    msg.setText(message.body);

    LinearLayout layout = vi.findViewById(R.id.message_layout);
    LinearLayout parent_layout = vi.findViewById(R.id.message_layout_parent);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // if message is mine then align to right
    if (message.isMine) {
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        int couleurBubble = getCouleurSelectionnee();

        switch(couleurBubble){
            case R.color.c1: msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_color1); break;
            case R.color.c2: msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_color2); break;
            case R.color.c3: msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_color3); break;
            case R.color.c4: msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_color4); break;
            case R.color.c5: msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_color5); break;
            case R.color.c6: msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_color6); break;
            case R.color.c7: msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_color7); break;
            case R.color.c8: msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_color8); break;
            default: break;
        }

        parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
    // If not mine then align to left
    else {
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bot_chat);
        parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
    return vi;
}
```

I don't really know where to go from here so any kind of help would be appreciated. If you want me to provide more code, let me know and I will.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to update the color in the getView from the adapter. Share that getView method from your adapter

Comment: Why do you have to use a list view. Is there something preventing you from using a recyclerview

Comment: @W0rmH0le Yes, I have tried that but unfortunately that only changes the color of the messages after I click back on the ```EditText``` where I type my message. I want the messages to change color as soon as I press the newly picked color. I added my getView method in the post in case you want to take a look.

Comment: To be honest I had never heard of a RecyclerView, I'll take a look at it and see if that solves my problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: call invalidade() in the listView

Comment: Try using recyclerview, list view is old and wont scale much.

Comment: @RicardoA. It looks like ```invalidate()``` is what I'm looking for but I'm not sure about where or when I have to call it. Is it in my ```getView``` method, or in the ```setOnClickListener``` that I posted above? And do I need to edit my ```ListView``` after I call it or does it do everything?

Comment: It would be in the onClick method. In the getView() you need to pass the new color though, but I think you're already doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sharing how I would do it. Maybe, this can help you.
There's some strange issue because you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This would be enough to re-draw all message bubbles.

My ideia is:

Add a `int` variable to the adapter class (`mColorResource`). This variable will point to the proper drawable that should be used (like `R.drawable.user_color1`).

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int mColorResource;

    ChatAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ChatData> list, int initialColorResource) {
        mContext = activity;
        chatMessageList = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // You must receive the color on the construtor
        mColorResource = initialColor;
    }

    // Use this method to update the color (when user select a new color)
    public void setColor(int newColorResource) {
        mColorResource = newColorResource;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        // Note how this if-else is cleaner now
        if (message.isMine) {
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            msg.setBackgroundResource(mColorResource);
            parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        } else {
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            msg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bot_chat);
            parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, when a color is selected, find the proper drawable based on the view clicked and pass it to the adapter:

```
ItemColor1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Couleur mise à jour", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        currentTheme = position;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("indexColorSelected", currentTheme);
        editor.apply();

        // Here, you send the proper drawable...
        // I'm not sure how you convert color selected to the drawable
        // So, add your logic to convert the button clicked to a drawable here
        // like R.drawable.user_color1
        chatAdapter.setColor(R.drawable.NAME_OF_THE_COLOR);

        // Request to re-draw all items from the list (all bubbles)
        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Also, on your activity, you create the adapter with the last used color. Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    // Set a default color (if user is open you app for the first time)
    int chatColor = R.drawable.user_color1;

    // Add your logic to read the shared preference and convert that last color used to a valid drawable.
    // Like chatColor = pref.getInt(indexColorSelected, R.drawable.user_color1) etc....

    // Set the color in the adapter.
    chatAdapter = newAdapter(this, mChatDataList, chatColor);
}
```